# Dart Streams - Is it possible to map to a new async stream?

Tags: dart, dart-stream

I might be getting confused with dart streams and RX related frameworks here.

But just wanted to check, is it possible to map to a new async stream?

For example

`apiService.signInStream` returns `Stream<signinResponse>`

`apiService.getUserDetailsStream` returns `Stream<userResponse>`

So I want to make the sign in call, take the user id from it to get the user details.

I tried something like this...

`apiService.signInStream(requestSignIn).asyncMap((event) => apiService.getUserDetailsStream(event.userId));`

But that returns...
`Stream<Stream<userResponse>>`

I'd like it to return `<Stream<userResponse>`

Do I have to listen within the map somehow?

Thanks

Comment: Use `Stream.asyncExpand`.

Answer (score 0):

You should listen:

```
apiService.signInStream(requestSignIn).listen((event) {
  apiService.getUserDetailsStream(event.userId)).listen((details) {
    // use event and details here
  });
});
```

Comment: Thats not ideal. If we make multiple api calls we end up with alot of nested listens.

Comment: @aidanmack Don't worry. This is the way streams work. It will not nest deeper than 2 levels. Assuming your `apiService.getUserDetailsStream` creates a stream per user.

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches and I cannot say which one you may use because I have no context of your project, all I have here are simply `Stream`s.

Lets begin:

> But that returns... `Stream<Stream<userResponse>>`

This is what return because this is what it is, you are iterating over a stream and returning another stream, streams are like lists, but asynchronous. Why do you want to ignore the `userResponse` stream? is this really a `Stream`? Why do not use a simply `Future` instead if you want just the returned data?

And since you're mapping the `signInStream`, I'll consider you:

- Wanna map each `signInStream` event
- Want just the first element of the `getUserDetailsStream`.

Run on DartPad: https://dartpad.dev/?id=17e2720be36c2bbde3da7d5a6381776d.

```dart
// What you have right now is:
final itIsWhatYouAreDoing = signInStream().asyncMap((event) => getUserDetailsStream());

// What you are saying you want to achieve:
final userDetailsStream = signInStream().asyncMap((event) async => await getUserDetailsStream().first);

print(itIsWhatYouAreDoing); // Stream<Stream<int>>
print(userDetailsStream); // Stream<int>
```

But this has some cons: you lose any other post-event emitted by all [getUserDetailsStream] Streams.

You didn't provide any detail about this, so I'll assuming they are irrelevant?!?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
apiService.signInStream(requestSignIn).asyncExpand((event) => 
    apiService.getUserDetailsStream(event.userId));
```

Remember to cancel the getUserDetailsStream otherwise your stream will be stuck waiting for getUserDetailsStream.

You can make use of takeWhile or take in dart to automatically kill the stream.